# How to navigate to the 'android.intent.action.MAIN' activity via the use of intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

Using a navigation drawer we can use an intent in the `onNavigationItemSelected` method.

To navigate to our second activity from the home (content_main) activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.userID.atp_jag.SecondActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

This transitions to the `SecondActivity` successfully, however:
When I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.userID.atp_jag.Home");
startActivity(intent);
```

The app crashes.
How do you navigate back to the home activity (the default e.g content_main) via intents?

Error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.userID.atp_jag.Home
```

Comment: First, we usually use explicit `Intents` (`new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)`) when working with activities in our own app. However, there is nothing magic about the "home activity" with respect to starting one. You will need to examine LogCat and look at the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: We surely need more information on the Home activity? There has to be a typo somewhere! Is the activity name real Home? Is it in the package `atp_jag`?

Comment: Updated the question with the error - I can't find a typo, I went through the same process that I did for the SecondActivity as for the Home one, except int he manifest file it has `'<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />'` instead of the package but using that doesn't work either.

Comment: @CommonsWare using your explicit intent fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you do not want to have `<intent-filter>` elements in your manifest, unless you are exposing that component to other apps. So, for example, the launcher activity has an `<intent-filter>`, because the point of the launcher activity is to be launched by home screens.

The corollary to this is that we usually use explicit `Intents` for starting our own activities. Implicit `Intents`, with action strings, is mostly for starting activities of other apps.

In your case, the error is because you created an implicit `Intent`, but for an action that does not exist. Switching to an explicit `Intent` should resolve that.